# How do you implement a simple list iterator in scheme?

Tags: loops, recursion, scheme

I'm trying to compare entries in a list of lists in Scheme using just the basic functions (car, cdr, cons, etc) but can't figure out how to iterate over a list. I tried writing this:

```
(define (iterate L X)
    (cond ((null? L) '())
          ((> X 0) (iterate ((cdr L) (- X 1))))
          ))
```

but I'm not sure why it doesn't work. My thinking is that iterate will just return the list of lists after n cdr's. So for example I'm trying to get:

```
(iterate ( ((10 20) (20 30) (30 40) (40 50)) '2)) -> ((30 40) (40 50))
(iterate ( ((10 20) (20 30) (30 40) (40 50)) '3)) -> ((40 50))
```

This is the error I get, no clue what it means:

```
*** ERROR: invalid application: (20 30)
Stack Trace:
_______________________________________
  0  (20 30)
        At line 45 of "./main.sc"
  1  ((10 20) (20 30) (30 40) (40 50))
        At line 45 of "./main.sc"
  2  (((10 20) (20 30) (30 40) (40 50)) '3)
        At line 45 of "./main.sc"
  3  (iterate (((10 20) (20 30) (30 40) (40 50)) '3))
        At line 45 of "./main.sc"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to use the list returned by `cdr` like it was a function that can be called.

Answer (score 0):

There are two fundamental problems:

1. You don't surround function arguments with parentheses in Scheme; the syntax is `(function arg1 arg2)`, not `(function (arg1 arg2))`. The latter first applies the procedure `arg1` to `arg2`, then passes the result of that to `function`.
2. `((10 20) (20 30) (30 40) (40 50))` does not create a list, it tries to apply the procedure `(10 20)` to the arguments `(20 30)`, `(30 40)` and `(40 50)`. Your implementation evaluates the first argument – `(20 30)` – first, before `(10 20)`, and this tries to apply `20` as a procedure to the argument `30`. This is the "invalid application".
   (If the procedure had been evaluated first you would have seen "invalid application: (10 20)".)

You need to either quote your list argument or use the `list` procedure.

Fixing these two problems gives

```
(define (iterate L X)
    (cond ((null? L) '())
          ((> X 0) (iterate (cdr L) (- X 1)))))
```

and

```
(iterate '((10 20) (20 30) (30 40) (40 50)) '3)
```

Now you only need to fix the problem that occurs when `X` reaches zero before the list is empty...

Answer (score 0):

Basically all control flow in Scheme, even the ones in the report, are syntax sugar for recursive procedures. Eg. when you would have written this in JS:

```
const arr = [];
for (let e of lst) {
  arr.push(e*2);
}
return arr;
```

In Scheme you would have written it like:

```
(define (loop lst acc)
  (if (null? lst)
      (reverse acc)
      (loop (cdr lst) (cons (* (car lst) 2) acc))))
(loop lst '())
```

And we have even a syntax sugar that does this more clearly:

```
(let loop ((lst lst) (acc '()))
  (if (null? lst)
      (reverse acc)
      (loop (cdr lst) (cons (* (car lst) 2) acc))))
```

In JS we have `Array.forEach`, `Array.reduce` and `Array.map`. In Scheme we have `for-each`, `fold-left`, `fold-right`, and `map`.  eg. The code above can be written like this in JS:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].map(v => v*2); // ==> [2, 3, 6, 8]
```

In like this in Scheme:

```
(map (lambda (v) (* v 2)) lst) ; ==> (2 3 6 8)
```

So I'm guessing you cannot use these list procedures, but you can create it by yourself or do roll your own recursion like my first example.